# How do I print out the files within a directory with C++ on a Mac?

Tags: c++, filesystems

I want to print out the files within a folder within my project but I can not figure out how to use filesystem. I am getting this error

```
error: no member named 'filesystem' in namespace 'std'
```

when running this code

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

int displayFileSystem() {
    std::string path = "UserContent/";
    for (const auto & entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(path))
        std::cout << entry.path() << std::endl;
}
```

I can't figure out why it is not letting me use the filesystem. I am relatively new to c++ and c and I do not understand everything the best so any helo would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using C++ 17? That's where `std::filesystem` was introduced.

Comment: how do I see if I am using 17?